# SyntaxError: Unexpected token t when using sattelizer and JAX-RS

Tags: angularjs, jax-rs, jwt, satellizer

Trying to return [JWT](http://jwt.io/) from JAX-RS webservice but get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token t
    at Object.parse (native)
    at fromJson (http://localhost:9081/FoodView/resources/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1250:14)
    at defaultHttpResponseTransform (http://localhost:9081/FoodView/resources/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9371:16)
    at http://localhost:9081/FoodView/resources/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9462:12
    at forEach (http://localhost:9081/FoodView/resources/bower_components/angular/angular.js:336:20)
    at transformData (http://localhost:9081/FoodView/resources/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9461:3)
    at transformResponse (http://localhost:9081/FoodView/resources/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10241:23)
    at processQueue (http://localhost:9081/FoodView/resources/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14634:28)
    at http://localhost:9081/FoodView/resources/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14650:27
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:9081/FoodView/resources/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15916:28)
```

This is my `LoginController` code from which I tries to perform login:

```
app.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $log, $auth){
    $scope.login = function() {
          $auth.login($scope.user)
            .then(function() {
              $log.info('You have successfully signed in');
              $location.path('/');
            })
            .catch(function(response) {
                $log.info(response.data, response.status);
            });
        };

});
```

And this is JAX-RS webservice code which issues JWT tokens, to generate JWT I'm using [jose.4.j](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Home) library:

```
@POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response mergeInfo(String json){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
        .setPrettyPrinting().create();

        System.out.println(json);

        String serializedJwe = null;
        try {
             Key key = new AesKey(ByteUtil.randomBytes(16));
             JsonWebEncryption jwe = new JsonWebEncryption();
             jwe.setPayload("Hello World!");
             jwe.setAlgorithmHeaderValue(KeyManagementAlgorithmIdentifiers.A128KW);
             jwe.setEncryptionMethodHeaderParameter(ContentEncryptionAlgorithmIdentifiers.AES_128_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256);
             jwe.setKey(key);
             serializedJwe = jwe.getCompactSerialization();
             System.out.println("Serialized Encrypted JWE: " + serializedJwe);
             jwe = new JsonWebEncryption();
             jwe.setKey(key);
             jwe.setCompactSerialization(serializedJwe);
             System.out.println("Payload: " + jwe.getPayload());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String token = "{token: " + serializedJwe + "}";

        return Response.ok(token).build();

    }
```

I think that format/way in which I return generated JWT is wrong, but can't realize how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Note that the jose4j code there is producing a JWE and not a JWT because the payload it just the string `"Hello World!"`.  Take a look at https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/JWT%20Examples for producing and consuming JWTs.

Comment: Hi, From the point of security is there any difference if I use JWE or JWT? For example if I need to store in payload only email of a user, can I use JWE?

Comment: There are lots of differences, too many to discuss here. A JWT is just a JWS or JWE (or nested JWS in a JWE) with JSON claims as the payload. The claims like aud, iss and exp do provide additional security context but may not always be necessary. Both JWS and JWE can be used with either symmetric or asymmetric keys/algorithms and the security characteristics differ. When issuing tokens that you'll also consume (maybe what your doing?), a JWE based JWT with a symmetric alg & a sub claim with the email but also an exp claim so it's not valid forever might be a minimalist solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I get the reason why it didn't work, my JSON string was misformatted.

This is correct string to parse it to json: `var test = '{"token":"test"}'`
So if you will perform: `JSON.parse(test)` you will get: `Object {token: "test"}`

**But!** If you will use string like this `var test = "{'token':'test'}"` to parse to javascript object, you will get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '`

So I've created in my Java application the following class:

```
public class Token {
    private String token;

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
}
```

And then changed the last 3 lines of my code to following:

```
        Token token = new Token();
        token.setToken(serializedJwe);

        return Response.ok(gson.toJson(token)).build();
```

Now everything works like expected.